# Como ejecutar una fuction Javascript en una tabla al momento de cargar mi página?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Estoy trabajando con MVC y c# y tengo una tabla que funciona con un foreach traído desde una base de datos SQL server, el problema está en un  que le devuelvo un dato en este caso un estatus y me lo muestra en un número, pero quiero modificarlo con javascript para me lo muestre con una palabra por ejemplo “Aprobado”, se cómo crear mi function, pero no sé cómo ejecutarla al momento que cargue la pagina

Este es el codigo de mi tabla

```
                                     <tbody>
                                            @foreach (DataRow row in Model.Rows)
                                            {
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="width:80px;">
                                                        <center>
                                                            <div class="img-container">
                                                                <img src=@Url.Action("ImagenPuntosTabla", "VBackend", new {CodigoP = @row["ID"]}) style="width:120px; height:120px; border-radius:25px;" />
                                                            </div>
                                                        </center>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td style="width:90px;">@row["Peligro"]</td>
                                                    <td style="width:80px;">@row["Zona"]</td>

                                                    <td style="width:80px;">@Convert.ToDateTime(row["Fecha"]).ToLongDateString()</td>
                                                    <td style="width:250px;">@row["comentario"]</td>
                                                    <td style="width:80px;">@row["Estatus"]</td>


                                                </tr>
                                            }
                                        </tbody>
```

Y este el de mi función javascript

```
<script>
                                                        function cambiarest(est) {
                                                            if (est = 0) {
                                                                document.getElementsByName("estado1")[0].value = "Aprovado";
                                                            }
                                                            else {
                                                                document.getElementsByName("estado2")[0].value = "Desaprovado";
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    </script>
```

Comment: ¿Porqué no cambiarle el texto en el _foreach_? ¿Necesariamente en JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

lo intentaste sin JS?
Podrias esta linia de codigos

```
<td style="width:80px;">@row["Estatus"]</td>
```

Por esta otra.

```
@{ if(row["Estatus"]==0){
<td style="width:80px;">Aprovado</td>
}
else{
<td style="width:80px;">Aprovado</td>
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Siempre puedes utilizar el evento **onload**  es decir añade lo siguiente

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     //Este parametro se lo tienes que pasar de alguna forma con C#
    <body onload="cambiarest(1)">


  <script>
      function cambiarest(est) {
          if (est == 0) {
              document.getElementsByName("estado1")[0].value = "Aprovado";
          } else {
              document.getElementsByName("estado2")[0].value = "Desaprovado";
          }
      }
  </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Nota: No se mucho de C#, pero si solo quiere ejecutar la función al cargar la página estoy seguro que con esto te va a funcionar

Ademas tienes un error en tu funcion. El = sirve para asignar. Para comparar puedes utilizar == o si ademas quieres comprobar el valor y el tipo de dato puedes utilizar ===

Espero haber sido claro y haberte ayudado!!!

Comment: Tengo una pregunta ese onload necesariamente tiene que ir en el body? o podria usarlo en la etiqueta <td> de la tabla

Comment: El evento onload se puede utilizar el las siguiente etiquetas, <body>, <img>, <script>, <iframe>  y con el html5 en algunas mas que no me acuerdo.